# Citing QGIS in formal publications

Tags: qgis, references

What is the best way to cite QGIS in a formal publication?  I mean, what text should be included in the References / Literature Cited section of a paper or report.

I'm also specifically referring to the software itself, rather than the user's manual. I've looked in the user's manual and in `Help > About`, but I can't find an answer.

Comment: Related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281248/citing-old-version-of-qgis-in-bibliography-of-assignment?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Start here: https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/faq/index.html#how-to-cite-qgis

> **Q: How to cite QGIS?**
>
> A: To cite QGIS software in your piece of work, for work or an
>   assignment, this general citation might be helpful: "QGIS
>   Development Team (YEAR). QGIS Geographic Information System.
>   Open Source Geospatial Foundation Project. http://qgis.osgeo.org".

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  Forgot to look there.  Maybe this info should be in the next version of the user's manual, if there are any of the great and good of QGIS reading this?

Comment: I was surprised it wasn't in the tips that popup when QGIS loads. I knew I saw it somewhere before and tabbed through all the tips before I checked the FAQ.

Answer (score 10):

from https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/QGIS_Citation_Repository

bibtex:

```
  @Manual{QGIS_software,
    title = {QGIS Geographic Information System},
    author = {{QGIS Development Team}},
    organization = {Open Source Geospatial Foundation},
    year = {2009},
    url = {http://qgis.org},
  }
```

which gives

> QGIS Development Team, 2009. QGIS Geographic Information System. Open
>   Source Geospatial Foundation. URL http://qgis.org

EDIT: I updated the url

Answer (score 2):

The present way to cite[1] is:

```
    @Manual{QGIS_software,
      title = {QGIS Geographic Information System},
      author = {{QGIS Development Team}},
      organization = {QGIS Association},
      year = {2021},
      url = {https://www.qgis.org},
    }
```

Personally I prefer to use the «program» type instead of manual. Zotero exports in RIS format:

```
TY  - COMP
TI  - QGIS Geographic Information System
AU  - QGIS Development Team
DA  - 2021///
PY  - 2021
PB  - QGIS Association
UR  - https://www.qgis.org
ER  -
```

[1] https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/faq/index.html#how-to-cite-qgis