# Citing old version of QGIS in bibliography of assignment?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.4

I've used QGIS 2.4.0-Chugiak to create maps for my assignment.
I would like to know what is the correct way to reference QGIS in-text and in the bibliography.

I've looked up [Citing QGIS in formal publications?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/23622/115) and I found that I'm supposed to use this:

> QGIS Development Team (YEAR). QGIS Geographic Information System. Open
>   Source Geospatial Foundation Project. http://qgis.osgeo.org

I've no idea what year I'm supposed to put in the parenthesis for the version I used and the link doesn't work for me. could someone please tell me in a clear way how I'm supposed to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QGIS 2.4 was released [27 June 2014](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/final-2_4_0).  The new URL is https://qgis.org.

Therefore I would use some thing like:

In your text:

> blah was blah blahed using QGIS 2.4 (preferred in-text citation style)

In your references/bibliograpy:

> QGIS Development Team (2014). QGIS Geographic Information System. Open Source Geospatial Foundation Project. https://qgis.org

Comment: Thank you so much! To clarify, when you say "preferred in-text citation method", would it be correct to write blah blah ...QGIS 2.4 (2014) under the map?

Comment: @Anna It depends on your preferred / required citation style. There are various standards.

Comment: It's a real shame that we cannot upvote comments occasionally :)