# How to cite a QGIS plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I need to cite in a scientific paper the Group Stats plugin (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/) of QGIS 3.

How should I cite it?

Comment: Related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23622/citing-qgis-in-formal-publications However, do not see particular instructions for plugins citation specifically

Comment: Another related post: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/14015

Answer (score 1):

For classical journal papers (printed/pdf), depending on [citation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_style_guides), you normally have the following information:

- Author(s)
- Publication year
- Title
- Journal Titel
- Volume, no. of issue
- pages
- URL/URI if applicable

Not everything applies to a plugin as well, but building on this principle, you could adapt it and cite it as follows:

> [Github user]  HenrikSpa (2021): GroupStats plugin for QGIS 3.
> Originally written by Rajmund Szostok. Version 2.2.5. URL:
> https://github.com/HenrikSpa/GroupStats [last accessed: 2021/05/18]

For academic use, it's always good to keep a local copy of all data, software etc. you use. Otherwise, you maybe won't be able to reproduce your results (and check for errors etc.) later on. Content might get lost on the internet...

---

See also:

- [How to cite and describe software](https://www.software.ac.uk/how-cite-software)
- [How to Cite Software in APA Style](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/01/how-to-cite-software-in-apa-style.html)
- [Citing & publishing software: How to cite software](https://libguides.mit.edu/c.php?g=551454&p=3900280)
- [Cite A Software in Harvard style](https://www.citethisforme.com/citation-generator/harvard/how-to-reference-software)